# How to open netrw at each vim session but have the cursor on the code (and not on the tree) when opening

Tags: netrw, startup, window-management

I found the following chunk of command on [this blog](https://shapeshed.com/vim-netrw/) to have a file browser open by starting vim that I added to my `.vimrc`. It splits the window into 2 panes: a file browser and the text editor. The active pane is the file browser one. When quitting (from the text editor pane), we have to quit the editor and then the file browser pane

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
augroup END
```

What I would like to do have as behaviour is:

1. To have the cursor on the text editor (and not on the file browser) when opening.
2. When closing from the text editor, I want to quit vim altogether (and not having to close the text editor and then close the file browser pane): to have the text editor as "master"

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to read [this article on project drawers](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)

Comment: For #2 you can quit vim with a single command even with multiple windows open using `:qa` or one of its variations (e.g. `:wqa` to write before quitting).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second VimScript command to be executed after `:Vexplore`.
Here `wincmd w` is equivalent to the <Ctrl+w>w key combination which toggles windows (see [Vim documentation: windows](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:wincmd)).

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore | wincmd w
augroup END
```

See also this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134759/running-a-vim-key-combination-on-startup